# Importing a list with python

Tags: python, https, proxy, io

I have a series of proxies (approximately 1000) that require authentication in order to login. The proxies are in `IP:PORT:USERNAME:PASSWORD` format.

I wish to be able to login with these proxies, and then be able to use each proxy to enter a specific piece of information that's dependent on the proxy. I want the format to be
`IP:PORT:USERNAME:PASSWORD:INFORMATION`.

For example

```
188.60.2.3:8080:Admin:Password:Cheese
76.48.3.1:8080:Admin:Password:Milk
```

And I want the "Information" part to be entered into a text box on a website.
So for example, the proxy 188.60.2.3 needs to input the information "Cheese" into a text box, and 76.48.3.1 needs to input "Milk".

I need to be able to do this automatically, and through importing a .txt file, and be able to login to the proxy and insert the information at the end of the proxy. 76.48.3.1 can only enter "Milk", and is not allowed to enter any other value.

How would I be able to make the list login to one proxy, enter the information at the end, and then go to the next proxy and repeat the process automatically with python?

This also requires HTTPS support.

Comment: I understand that perfectly.

It's more or less being able to grab the "Milk" part of the line, and being able to go to the next line, that I do not know about.

If the format is IP:PORT:USERNAME:PASSWORD:INFORMATION, how would I make it grab the "INFORMATION"?

Comment: have a look at http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/ for the "entering information into a text box" part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to read tabular delimited data is to use [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) along with an appropriate `Dialect`.